# instead of fill labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

It gets too confusing with all the colors in the legend. I try to get (at best rotated) labels under each bar. So instead of having the fill colors I want labels.

I played around with library(directlabels) and some more stuff but didn't succeed.

sample code:

```
Assets <- cbind(c(rep("Index",13),rep("Aktie",4),rep("Rohstoffe",6),rep("Währungen",3), rep("Bonds",4)),
            c("DAX","MDAX","SDAX","TecDAX","CAC","FTSE","ATX","BUX","SandP","TA-100","TOPIX","DOW","NASDAQ","Asien","Europa","USA","Sonstige","Gold","Silber","OIL","Cotton","Sugar","Pork","USD-EUR","JPY-USD","JPY-EUR","BOBL","BUND","US_10","US_30"))
colnames(Assets) <- c("Asset_Cat","Asset_Name")
TestD <- data.frame(Land       = sample(c("GER","UK","POL","CH","YP"), 1000, replace = T),
                    P1         = sample(1:100, 10000, T)*sample(1:100, 10000, T),
                    P2         = sample(1:100, 10000, T)*sample(1:100, 10000, T),
                    P3         = sample(1:100, 10000, T)*sample(1:100, 10000, T))
TestD    <- cbind(Assets[sample(nrow(Assets), length(TestD$Land), replace = T), ],TestD)


ggplot(data = TestD, aes(x = Asset_Cat, y = P1, fill=Asset_Name)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
labs(x="", y="Anzahl pro 1000 Datenpunkten") +
ggtitle("Eve") +
theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

What I try to get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzrsC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your plot:

```
  ... +
    geom_text(aes(y = -1, label = Asset_Name), 
             angle = 90, hjust = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.35,0))
```

[image]